# Cron failed with drush: Segmentation fault

Tags: 6, drush, cron

In Drupal 6, whenever I run cron from web interface I get an Internal server error and when I run

```
drush cron
```

I just get

```
Segmentation fault
```

What can be wrong here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a resource problem.  Memory limits tend to be the culprit.

Check to see that drush is using the same php.ini file your site is.

```
drush status
```

Tells you what php you are using for drush.

Running the following will give you memory output information when running cron

```
drush cron -d
```

if that memory stack is near what your php.ini limit is.. raise it up an integer of 32Mb. (i.e. 128mb to 160mb)  and then test again.

Comment: This happened to me not long ago, in preconfigured VM's I had to work with, when I am in devel mode, *especially* with theme_devel enabled. I simply pushed up memory setting in php as this answer states at the end.

Comment: The first bit of advice is important.  I have seen system installs where the web and CLI versions of PHP have different ini files.

Comment: Well, drush uses /etc/php5/cli/php.ini. I set memory_limit=512M and retried after issuing 'drush --yes vset cron_semaphore 0' (otherwise cron would not run). But now after issuing 'drush cron -d' I still get  a bunch of bootstraps which end up with: 'Initializing drush commandfile: user [0.29 sec, 42.79 MB]                                                  [bootstrap] Segmentation fault

Comment: I had the same problem with a 5.x version of drush.... downgrade to 4.6 and see if you are getting the same error..

Comment: @PhiloSurfer I'm using drush 4.5.

Comment: up to 4.6-dev and see if this resolves... there are some drush bugs floating around.

Answer (score 0):

After starting cron from the web interface check your apache access and error logs for more information.

When starting cron with drush, make sure you have xdebug installed. It can record traces, memory usage and give you a stack trace in case php crashes.

Comment: Well, I am using nginx+php-fpm, not apache. Can I still install xdebug? How?

Answer (score 0):

[According to Metaltoad](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/fix-drupal-segmentation-fault), Views (among other modules that execute regexs with `preg_match()`) can create runaway regex's that eat up memory and cause segfaults because [`preg_match()` can't prevent backtracking overflows](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45735#1365812629).